# Memory management : how to reset a list correctly

Tags: java, memory

In terms of memory used and impact on garbage collector, I would like to know if there is a difference between those two implementations :

```
protected List<T> _data = new ArrayList<T>();

// I want to reset this list using another one. First try :
public void set(List<T> newData) {
    _data = newData;
}

// I want to reset this list using another one. Second try :
public void set(List<T> newData) {
    _data.clear();
    _data.addAll(newData);
}
```

Also, if there is any functional difference, please tell me !

Comment: You shouldn't worry about the GC. It knows what it does.

Comment: In the first case, you're copying the List instance.  In the second case, you're creating a shallow copy of the contents of the List.  The first is better for internal callers, callers you trust.  If you don't trust the caller, you want to make a deep copy of the contents of the List.

Comment: Just to be clear : I don't focus into optimizing that piece of code, but on the other hand I would need a criteria to choose between these pieces of code. I thought performance could be one, but data "security" is even better. Hence the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one just replaces its reference to a list with the one provided by the caller.  If the old list isn't reachable from anywhere else, it is eligible for GC.

The second uses the object's existing list, and copies each of the caller's list's item references into it.  If that increases the size of the collection, then that may involve allocating a bigger array internally (making the smaller array collectible).

The reachability of the items themselves does not change; both versions cause the lists to refer to the exact same items.

The first is typically quite a bit faster, since you're replacing a single reference.  That's less work than copying a bunch of references from one list into another.

The second, though, is generally better from an encapsulation point of view.  Imagine this...

```
yourThingie.set(myItems);
myItems.add(objectYouNeverWouldHaveAllowed);
```

With the first version, `_data` now contains `objectYouNeverWouldHaveAllowed`.  You can no longer enforce your class's constraints on `_data`; since you've let the caller smuggle their own list in there, they now have control over your object's internal state.  They can break your object from a distance, even accidentally.

The second doesn't have such a problem.  You retain control of `_data`, the caller's subsequent changes to their list don't affect you, and if you're not doing something broken (like providing a getter that retrieves the naked object), you're safe.

Comment: That's a very good point ! I had not thought about the possibility of insertion afterwards ! That's actually a kind of functional difference.

Comment: Second version is also potentially unsafe depending upon whether or not each element of the should be modifiable by an outside agent (unless the list contains built-in values like 'int').  You then have the question of 'should all elements of the list be cloned?'.  what if you have a list of 10000 Point's - you have to allocate a clone of each point on the heap in addition to the list storage itself.  I thought Java was supposed to be safer than C++ but after using it for a couple of weeks I get more and more horrified by it.

Comment: @Pete:  It's pretty simple, really.  If your thingie can change, integrity all but demands that you have your own private copy of it.  So yes, a list of 10000 mutable points would also need each point cloned.  This kind of thing is part of what makes unnecessary mutability evil, and is an argument in favor of an *immutable* "point" type.  C++ has the opposite problem, if you care about performance -- it deep-clones by default, even if the things being cloned are immutable.  You have to actually override the copy constructor and/or use references or pointers (or `shared_ptr`s) to prevent that.

Comment: @cHao Totally agree - the lack of 'const' in Java results in so many breakages of encapsulation for very innocent looking code..  At least it is possible to handle all cases in C++ and if you write the code properly the resulting interface gives the caller an indication of the mutability constraints.  In the case of copying a Point vector, the deep copy is 1 allocation and 1 (large-ish) memcpy, assuming the point class does not have a user defined constructor.  In Java, it is 10001 allocations and 10000 function calls to some clone function.

Comment: @Pete: s/constructor/copy constructor/.  As long as the object is "trivially copyable", a copy constructor doesn't need to run.  (There's nothing saying C++ *can't* use a copy constructor, if it knows it's copying objects, but many compilers will just do a bitwise copy instead.)  The definition of "trivially copyable" doesn't preclude a regular constructor, though -- only copy/move constructors are disqualifying.

Comment: @Pete: Back to the point... Java can handle all cases too; it merely requires (just like C++) that you add code to handle the non-default case.  The default is different, is all.  Reference (identity) semantics are the default in Java, while value semantics are the default in C++.

Comment: @cHao how do you avoid all that GC going on - more of an issue for devices with limited memory where this would be an issue?

Comment: @Pete: Depends on the situation.  The only near-universal way is to simply avoid creating objects you don't need.  If that's not an option, then a type more tailored to the situation might be in order.  You could have something like a class that represents a bunch of points.  One array of ints (twice the size of the collection) might contain the data, and cloning the object would just mean cloning that array.

Comment: @cHao yeah I was thinking that would be the solution.  Not particularly OO though.  So in general it would be better to have getters like `void getThing(Thing thing);` rather than `Thing getThing();`, with the first option copying by value into the passed parameter, to avoid encapsulation breakage and unnecessary GC?  Is that a common idiom in Java?

Comment: @Pete: Common?  Not really.  The only time i think i ever really see it is in cases like `java.io`, where you have a mutable buffer you want filled with data.  As for "not particularly OO", though, it's just a different take on OO.  You still have an encapsulated collection of objects; they're just arranged differently.  And it'd be trivial to provide lightweight objects that simply have the collection reference and an index, and encapsulate each item.  Those wouldn't even need copying during a clone; they could be created on the fly if they didn't already exist.

Answer (score 3):

The first example, replaces the old object with the new one.  This is fine if you have created a new List each time any way.  If your set() should take a copy of the list because it might be changed by the caller, the second example might be worth considering.

The second example, reuses the List and this can be

- good as it save creating a copy.
- bad because you can have a object in tenured space which references lots of young objects.  If this happens enough it will slow down your GC times.

In general, you should do what you believe is the simplest solution and worry about performance when you have measured your application e.g. with a memory profiler. and it tells you have an issue.  Unless you measure, you are just guessing.

AFAIK, no Java JVM supports reference counting for memory management.  If it not forbidden by the standard but is has too many problems to consider using it in Java. e.g. circular references. Fun fact, smart pointers in C++ use reference counting :(

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use the first method where you used `_data = newData;`. _data is a pointer to a list. So by doing that what you will do is you will cause _data to point to newData. Since whatever _data was pointing to before is not being pointed to anymore, then garbage collector will dispose of it.

Your second method however is quite costly, and I wouldn't do it. Yes it achieves same thing, but instead of simply shifting pointer it does more computation which will cost you.

Answer (score 0):

The first is a single reference assignment.  The second has to copy the list of references from 'newData' into '_event', possibly resizing '_event' in the process, which entails further copying.

BUT... "Premature optimization if the root of all evil."  (If that doesn't ring a bell, look it up!)

The *semantic* difference is probably more important in most cases.  In the first you are just referencing the data provided to 'set' - if the calling code later changes it, it is changed in '_events' too (because '_events' IS 'newData').  This could cause dangerous side effects, if it wasn't intended.

In the second, subsequent changes to 'newData' are not reflected as changes to '_events' because '_events' is a copy of new data.  Which is right is down to the semantics of your application.  The same applies, in reverse, if you have a 'get' matching this 'set'.

If you are going to be updating only the contents of '_events' rather than changing what it references, you should also consider making it final.

Hmmm.  I just noticed that '_data' is only mentioned once in your example.  I have assumed above that '_data' and '_events' are the same thing (i.e. it is a typo) - otherwise why would you mention '_data' at all?

Answer (score 0):

The major differences are:

List Implementation:
The `List` passed in may not be an `ArrayList`, it may be (for example) a `LinkedList`. Simply using the list passed in may severely impact the performance of your application if you directly access elements of your list via their index; `ArrayList.get(i)` is O(1), but `LinkedList.get(i)` is O(n).

Data Integrity:
If you simply use that list handed you, the caller may keep a reference to it and (much) later modify the list *without your class knowing*. This may cause unpredictable behaviour in your application. For example, you may store information about the list's contents, which would then be invalid in the list was modified without your class's knowledge, leading to data inconsistency. Likewise, your class may modify the list, and the client wouldn't (usually) know, so the converse may be true - the client may have data inconsistencies.

Memory leak:
A reference to the list may be held by both the caller and your class. This may lead to the list not being garbage collected when expected by either.

For these reasons (and probably more), best practice is normally to *copy* the list passed in, unless there is a good reason not to, *and* the fact that you're not making a copy is well documented so that everybody knows what the implications are.